# Granting access to a different subdomain in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

We have a Symfony2 application that gives customers their own subdomain. We want people within our company, with the customer's permission, to access the customer's subdomains by impersonating the admin of that subdomain.

We use FOSUserBundle to centralise the admins.

Is this possible, and if so, what are the options impersonating users on different subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

May be you solve your problem using third parameter login.

I have my own authentication firewall, and my users access the system with credentials and selecting organisation.
If this solve your problem I can help you.
But it's hard to explain and I don't use FosUserBundle.
Tell me if that it's what you wants to avoid write a lot for nothing.

You're sure?
both pictures taken from my system

[image: Manage user's organizations (many-to-many)]

[image: Login screen]

In this case organisations and subdomains are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think that's directly relevant to the question. This question specifically addresses granting access to a different subdomain.

Comment: I edit the post above, another way could be using URLs routing and access_control config.

Comment: So it looks like you have a similar setup to me (users having their own subdomains). Do your staff have access to your customer areas? If so, please post some examples to help me. I'm not sure if it'll necessarily work, but it's worth a shot. To reiterate, users can access their own subdomains just fine, but the hard bit is overriding this mechanism to allow a staff member to log in from the main subdomain onto a user's subdomain.

Comment: I use Gedmo Tree extension through stof's bundle for organisation (subdomains) tree.

Comment: I use Gedmo Tree extension through stof's bundle for organisation (subdomains) tree. When user is logged in, has a custom UserOrganizationToken and this token holds organisation info. The data stored on database are associated to organisation and hierarchical data can be retrieved avoiding recursivity thanks to Gedmo Tree.

Comment: Using joins I can say something like "give me all data associated to current user's organisation and data from child nodes". I hope you can get what I talking about.